# SSIS Connection to Excel via ACE.OLEDB as Service Account

Tags: excel, ssis, oledb, drivers

We have a process which needs to work with a series of Excel (*sigh*) files.

The setup is:

SQL agent job run as a SSIS proxy account.
Calls SSIS package on a share on the server.
Which then starts accessing these excel files using the ACE driver.

- The process will work under my credentials.
- The process will work under other people's credentials.
- The process will work in debug mode (although this is not a fair test
  as that would use my local machine's driver)

---

- The process will not work using the SSIS proxy account.
- The process WILL work if I make the SSIS proxy account an
  administrator  on the server.

I have ruled out the following:

1. access to the files share. The account can load text files from
   there.
2. 32bit/64bit issues. The account CAN run given sufficient
   permissions.

My opinion is that the service account needs some sort of level of permission to be able to use the driver. I can't work out what though.

I have tried LOCAL SECURITY POLICY option "Load and unload device drivers" with no success. ( I did think this had done it, but then realised that I had left the account in the admin group :-(  )

Finally, the error message in question:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. 
>   The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager
>   "TPR_ReadReportsExcelConnection" failed with error code 0xC0202009. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Comment: Trying to understand what you've ruled out and why. You make the proxy account a member of the Administrators group on the machine and everything works. Take them out of the role and things go belly up? Is the Proxy account a service account or a user account? If service, does it have the ability to interact with the desktop? If you think it's a permissions thing, why not test by granting explicit access to the ACE install path?

Comment: `There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed` - what other error messages were there?

Comment: Sorry no other messages before this coming from SSIS. The account is a service account. How would I know it has the ability to interact with the desktop? I will try giving the account access to the installer path, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be beyond the supported scope depending on how you've set up your SSIS proxy account.  See Additional Information section [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).  Not enough points to post an image so here is the important sentence:

*provided the SSIS jobs run in the context of a logged-on user with a valid HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry hive*

Comment: This seems like a promising route to explore. How would one allow the service account to function in this way? As an administrator it is able to function this way.

Comment: Well let's clarify, given my answer has been down voted, I may have the wrong end of the stick.  Is the SSIS proxy account logged on as one of the built in user accounts: 'Network Service','Local System','Local Service' or is it logged on as something like DOMAIN\user?

Comment: I'm not an expert when it comes to these kinds of things obviously. As far as I can tell, the account does not logon to the server. It logs into SQL Server instance, there it has sufficient permission to execute SSIS packages via agent job which reside on the sever's fileshare. The name of the account is indeed domain\user.

Comment: Ok.  So my mistake with that answer, I hope you didn't waste any time going down that route.  So I think I'm right in saying you have confirmed the proxy account set up on the SQL Server is correct because as long as you put the account in the Administrators group it will run the job.  So have you verified the DCOM config is correct?  The proxy account should have permission to launch/ activate the DCOM object as in this [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/robert_davis/2008/08/13/How-do-I-grant-access-permissions-for-SSIS-to-users/)